Ethereum Geth Node for writing transactions
We are running a full Ethereum Geth node, but the resources and support effort is too great.
All we need to do is create ETH addresses and send transaction, not read or scan the blockchain.
Can anyone suggest a good method for creating a Geth node for only creating transctions, not maintaining the blockchain history?
Cheers Peter

There are services that provide RPC access to nodes on the cloud. Did you try some of those services? They should be cheaper if you only need to send transactions.
